# Making a Bootstrap 4 multi image carousel slider

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap-4

I am working with this Bootstrap 4 carousel slider and instead of having it scroll 3 images at a time I am trying to have it scroll 4 images at a time. How would I best go about making this happen? And it does have to be Bootstrap 4 also. Thanks!

https://www.codeply.com/go/s3I9ivCBYH/multi-carousel-single-slide-bootstrap-4

Comment: First make an effort to understand how the snippet you've referenced works.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap carousel actually uses a div for each slide. That would mean you can insert more images inside each slide with proper sizing.

```
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="" src="http://placebeard.it/g/640/480" alt="First slide">
      <img class="" src="http://placebeard.it/g/640/480" alt="First slide">
      <img class="" src="http://placebeard.it/g/640/480" alt="First slide">
      <img class="" src="http://placebeard.it/g/640/480" alt="First slide">
    </div>
```

Here's a working sample in codepen : https://codepen.io/asimaley/full/RZvgLr